# Two font awesome arrows with one on top of the other with a circle around them

Tags: html, css

I have this image:

[image]

and I tried to do the same in `HTML` and `CSS`, with two font awesome icons. I put the `position:absolute` for one of the icon to be close to the other. I tried to make the circle around but without any success. Someone please give me a hand.

```css
.formular {
  position: relative;
 }
 .formular a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right {
   font-size: 17px;
   color: #000;
 }
 .circle {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #dce0e1;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right:first-child {
   position: absolute;
   left: 4px;
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right:last-child {
   position: relative;
 }
 .formular .text {
   font: normal 15px 'CenturyGothic-Bold';
   color: #028A92;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="formular">
  <a href="#" title="Click here">
   <span class="circle">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="text">Ask for our forms</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't really need FA for that. Simple : ⏩    You could also combine with CSS two ▶ in order to tune the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have change this

```
.formular .circle {
         background: #efeded none repeat scroll 0 0;
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #000;
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 7px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

<span class="circle">
                <i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <!--<i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
            </span>
```

```css
.formular {
  position: relative;
 }
 .formular a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right {
   font-size: 17px;
   color: #000;
 }
 .formular .circle {
      background: #efeded none repeat scroll 0 0;
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #000;
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 7px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right:first-child {
   position: absolute;
   left: 4px;
 }
 .circle .fa-caret-right:last-child {
   position: relative;
 }
 .formular .text {
   font: normal 15px 'CenturyGothic-Bold';
   color: #028A92;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="formular">
  <a href="#" title="Click here">
   <span class="circle">
    <i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <!--<i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
   </span>
   <span class="text">Ask for our forms</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a bit more padding on .circle class, 
eg:

```
 .circle { padding: 10px }
```

This is not the best way to create this button, but as you just wanted a hand, hope that helps. :)

You will have to play around adjusting the shape of the circle a bit more to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Small Change In Css. 
check the link below may Help You

```
    .circle .fa-caret-right:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;

}
.circle .fa-caret-right:last-child {
  position: relative;
 left: 5px;
}
```

`visit the link:` https://jsfiddle.net/crxsL3qt/